# Can anyone explain how can i query on ProfileApexClassAccess and ProfileApexPageAccess objects

Tags: apex, standard-objects

Can anyone explain how can i query on `ProfileApexClassAccess` and `ProfileApexPageAccess` objects?

Answer (score 2):

This are not objects that can be queried using SOQL, they are actually part of the [Profile](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_meta/Content/meta_profile.htm) data structure ([ProfileApexClassAccess](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_meta/Content/meta_profile.htm#profileApexClassAccess_title), [ProfileApexPageAccess](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_meta/Content/meta_profile.htm#profileApexPageAccess_title)) returned by the [Salesforce Metadata API](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_meta/) via the [Retrieve operation](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_meta/Content/meta_retrieve.htm), which is notoriously hard to use in respect to retrieving Profile information.

If you want to use SOQL to query profile information you can do this by leveraging the fact that for each [Profile object](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_profile.htm) in an org, a [Permission Set record](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_permissionset.htm) is created, thus you can query the [SetupEntityAccess](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_setupentityaccess.htm) child object, the documentation for this object has this example for Apex Classes.

```
SELECT Id, ParentId, Parent.Name, SetupEntityId FROM SetupEntityAccess 
  WHERE SetupEntityType='ApexClass'
```

Which can be adapted for ApexPage's like so...

```
SELECT Id, ParentId, Parent.Name, SetupEntityId FROM SetupEntityAccess 
  WHERE SetupEntityType='ApexPage'
```

Here is the schema diagram as is also provided in the documentation...

[image]